# signalr example not working

Tags: signalr

i just installed the signalr sample (downloaded with nuget)

everything from nuget installed fine and it's a clean project (just to test the sample), yet i get the following error:

throw "SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()";

Comment: i am trying to run the latest stock ticker example 'as is', which i downloaded straight from the site. i have changed nothing of the code.

Comment: tbh I found the stock ticker a little involved to get started with, so I ended up trying something simpler. I found this one useful: http://vimeo.com/43659069

Answer (score 8):

use package manager

```
install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

and do changes in startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker.Startup), "Configuration")]

namespace Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker


{

    public static class Startup
    {
        public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker.Startup.ConfigureSignalR(app);
        }
        public static void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the errors I got with the sample. Server side errors fetching the hubs JS file: "No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute."; "No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class."

Answer (score 1):

Replace code in Startup.cs file with the following code block, that will fix the js error hopefully

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker.Startup))]
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker
{
    public static class Startup
    {
        public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
             app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have first to call,

```
$.connection.hub.start
```

for example :

```
var myConnection = $.connection.myConnection;
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'auto' }, function () {
    alert('connected');
});
/// now you can do what ever you want.
myConnection.SendHello('Just Testing');
```

now when you load open the page, you should see the browser message (connected), to make sure that the signalR has established a connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full working demo with source code at :

[Example including VS2010 solution](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=780)

This worked for me first time.